# What's the point of the second argument in element.classList.toggle?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList):

> The toggle method has an optional second argument that will force the class name to be added or removed based on the truthiness of the second argument. For example, to remove a class (if it exists or not) you can call `element.classList.toggle('classToBeRemoved', false);` and to add a class (if it exists or not) you can call `element.classList.toggle('classToBeAdded', true);`

To my understanding, the `classList` is a token list, and lists, unlike arrays, can't have duplicate items. So adding an item to a list that already has it doesn't do anything and removing an item from a list that doesn't contain it (obviously) doesn't do anything, meaning that `classList.toggle(className, true)` is identical to `classList.add(className)` and `classList.toggle(className, false)` is identical to `classList.remove(className)`.

Am I missing something?

P.S. no need to warn about IE compatibility issues.

Comment: I believe you are correct in that `classList.toggle(className, false)` is identical to `classList.remove(className)`. However, using `false` is just a basic example. It is conceivable that there are scenarios where a conditional statement could be passed in as the second parameter. I can't think of an example off the top of my head, but this might be the purpose of it.

Comment: @Rudie Is there any difference between `add` and `toggle(x, true`)?
Is there any difference between `remove` and `toggle(x, false`)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It would simply allow you to do something like this:

```
el.classList.toggle("abc", someBool);
```

instead of this:

```
if (someBool) {
    el.classList.add("abc");
} else {
    el.classList.remove("abc");
}
```

Comment: Or `el.classList[someBool ? 'add' : 'remove']('abc')` for extra readability!

Comment: @Rudie - your suggestion is extra verbosity, not as elegant as `toggle`. Also, `toggle` will *add* the class if `someBool` is `undefined`, which is *desirable*, where your (comment's) snippet will not

Answer (score 5):

Unlike classList.add()/remove() `classList.toggle()` returns true when a class is added, and false when it’s removed — add() and remove() return undefined.

FYI IE11 doesn't support the optional 2nd add/remove param to `classList.toggle()`.

Comment: I am glad that you pointed the difference. But what you've said isn't precise. It returns second argument of toggle. It's a little bit different. Let's say we don't have some class `myclass` but performing elem.classList.toggle('myclass',false) is going to return false (even though we clearly didn't remove it - there just wasn't a presence of the class in the first place).

Answer (score 1):

`classList.toggle` like

```js
el.classList.toggle("abc", someBool)
```

is equivalent to :

```js
let  hasClass  = el.classList.contains('abc')
  ;
if ( someBool && !hasClass ) el.classList.add('abc')
if (!someBool &&  hasClass ) el.classList.remove('abc')
```

To be more precise, with the return value:

```js
function ToggleForce( element, nameOfClass, condition )
  {
  let hasClass = element.classList.contains( nameOfClass )
    ;
  if ( condition != hasClass )
    {
    if (hasClass) element.classList.remove( nameOfClass )
    else          element.classList.add( nameOfClass )
    // hasClass = !hasClass
    }
  return condition // hasClass
  }
```

The documentation on using this second argument `force` is a bit weak.
Ultimately, the value of this condition determines whether the specified class(s) should be present(s) or not.
The subtlety of this argument is that it first checks whether it really needs to do an [add or remove] operation (a few microseconds saved?).
It's a bit counterintuitive, like many others I thought this boolean was being used to validate / invalidate the Toggle operation, and sure enough it seemed a little silly to me, the term Toggle might not be adequate, but now that I understand, I see no other possible.

Proof:
(with some elements for comparisons)

```js
function ToggleForce( element, nameOfClass, condition )
  {
  let hasClass = element.classList.contains(nameOfClass)
    ;
  if ( condition != hasClass)
    {
    if (hasClass) element.classList.remove(nameOfClass)
    else          element.classList.add(nameOfClass)
    // hasClass = !hasClass
    }
  return condition
  }

btAdd.onclick =_=> { pElem.classList.add('toYellow');   console.clear() }
btRem.onclick =_=> { pElem.classList.remove('toYellow');console.clear() }
btTog.onclick =_=>
  {
  let res = pElem.classList.toggle('toYellow')
  console.clear()
  console.log(`toggle simple  : return = ${res}`)
  }
btTo5.onclick =_=>
  {
  let res = pElem.classList.toggle('toYellow', val.valueAsNumber<5)
  console.clear()
  console.log(`toggle force:(value < 5)=${val.valueAsNumber<5}, return=${res}`)
  }
btToT.onclick =_=>
  {
  let res = pElem.classList.toggle('toYellow', true)
  console.clear()
  console.log(`toggle force:true, return=${res}`)
  }
btToF.onclick =_=>
  {
  let res = pElem.classList.toggle('toYellow', false)
  console.clear()
  console.log(`toggle force:false, return=${res}`)
  }
btForce.onclick =_=> 
  {
    console.clear()

  let condition  = (val.valueAsNumber < 5)
    , hasClass   = pElem.classList.contains('toYellow')
    ,  msg       = 'no change'
    , classOnOff = ToggleForce( pElem, 'toYellow', (val.valueAsNumber<5) )
    ;
  //
  if ( condition && !hasClass ) msg = ' add class'
  if (!condition &&  hasClass ) msg = ' remove class'
  console.log(`return=${classOnOff}, condition=${condition}, hasClass=${hasClass}, --> ${msg}`)
  }
```

```css
.toYellow{ background: yellow; }
```

```html
<p id="pElem">test zone for class .toYellow { background: yellow; } </p>

value : <input id="val" type="number" value="6">
<br><br>

<button id="btAdd"> Add class </button>
<button id="btRem"> Remove class </button>
<br><br>
<button id="btTog"> tooggle simple</button>
<button id="btTo5"> toggle('toYellow', value < 5) </button>
<br><br>
<button id="btToT"> tooggle true </button>
<button id="btToF"> tooggle false </button>
<br><br>
<button id=btForce> <b>toggle('toYellow', value < 5)</b> <br> simulated by Add / remove method </button>
```

Comment: @Rudie you should take a look at my answer;)