# Append class to div when screen size is below breakpoint

Tags: javascript

So I'm having some trouble executing some items and I wanted to see if I can get the help from some experts on how I might be able to execute this:

So here is what I'm attempting to achieve:

- When browser either loads or resizes and it's below `769px`, I want to add the classname '`is-right` to my dropdown.
- If the screen is bigger than `769px`, I want to remove the `is-right` classname.

Here is what I currently have:

```
<div class="level-item">
    <div class="dropdown is-hoverable is-clickable">
        // Empty
    </div>
</div>
<div class="level-item">
    <div class="dropdown is-hoverable is-clickable">
        // Empty
    </div>
</div>
```

The class name have to appended on the list with: `dropdown is-hoverable is-clickable`, so it's be like this: `dropdown is-hoverable is-clickable is-right`.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    const dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown');

    // If window screen is at least 500px
    if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 769px)").matches) {
        dropdown.classList.toggle('is-right')
    } else {
        dropdown.classList.remove('is-right');
    }
});
```

The above snippet for some reason won't append the `.is-right` to my dropdown, keep in mind I have multiple .dropdown classes.

Comment: why don't you simply use css media query ?

Comment: I'm using the Bulma Framework and they have a classname that has all the css for `is-right`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loop through querySelectorAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51810655/loop-through-queryselectorall)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly I think for your code to do what you are expecting it to do, you should change this : `window.matchMedia("(min-width: 769px)").matches`

to :

```
window.matchMedia('(max-width: 769px)').matches
```

This will mean that the matchMedia.matches evaluates to true when the window is below a width of 769px, instead of false as it is right now.

This works, with the change :

```
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
const dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown');

    // min-width changed to max-width
if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 769px)').matches) {
    dropdown.classList.toggle('is-right');
} else {
    dropdown.classList.remove('is-right');
}
});
```

Finally, I think a slightly more elegant solution while keeping your current implementation would be something like this :

```
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
    const dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown');
    dropdown.classList.toggle('is-right', window.matchMedia('(max- 
    width:769px)').matches);
});

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    const dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown');
    dropdown.classList.toggle('is-right', window.matchMedia('(max- 
    width:769px)').matches);
});
```

As per the documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) classList.toggle() allows for a condition to be set when it is called. We just add the matchMedia.matches property, which will evaluate to either true or false, into the conditional statement.

*UPDATED*

I couldn't find a lot of information about how toggle works, but after testing for an hour or so, it seems that toggle will try and add the class provided if the conditional statement evaluates to true, and it will try and remove it if the conditional statement evaluates to false. So by just adding the 'is-right' class (with classList.toggle) when the document loads, our other 'elegant' solution will still work perfectly in conjunction with that. Codepen is updated to reflect that. Let me know if this works for you, and I hope I was able to help.

https://codepen.io/KXNG420/pen/yLaMQgV

Comment: The more elegant method is so nice! How would I make it so I can use both resize and load in the elegant solution? - I'm currently calling two `addEventListener`'s and wrapped it inside a function.

Comment: So I've been trying to find information about toggle for the last hour or so, without a lot of luck, but I do have an elegant solution that seems to work for me, and I would love to know if it works for you. I have updated the CodePen, permanently this time, and will update my answer accordingly. My understanding of how toggle works with a conditional, and please correct me if I'm wrong, is that if the condition is evaluated to true, then toggle will attempt to add the class, and if it evaluates to false then it will attempt to remove the class.

Comment: I saw that; not sure if OP is looking to apply the class to only the first div with the .dropdown class, or all of them. My answer is using 'querySelector' as per the original question, which only selects the first element that matches the query. If OP needs to apply the change to all of them they could use 'querySelectorAll' and then loop through the NodeList that is returned.

Comment: I have made some investibation about `classList.toggle()` second argument, here it is : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23663151/whats-the-point-of-the-second-argument-in-element-classlist-toggle/65315418#

Comment: That link you provided explains how our implementation is correct. We are providing a conditional statement, which will sometime evaluate to true, and sometimes to false, depending on the screen size. In the link provided classList.toggle('some-class', false) will always evaluate to false, which is why it is basically the same as classList.remove(). Hopefully this clears up any confusion you may have

Comment: Also, the explicit answer to the question that was asked was to change 'min-width' to 'max-width'. Anything else is superfluous. Your answer does not address the main reason why OP's code was not doing what he expected it to do.

Comment: thanks, you're right, I didn't fully understand the point of the second argument in the toggle method.

Comment: Anytime, it's honestly really understandable because it's so hard to find a lot of information about specifically the toggle part of class list. I hadn't found that article so I appreciate you linking it.

Answer (score 2):

This way  should working (?)

```js
function Sizing4isRight() 
  {
  let classOnOff = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 769px)').matches  
    ;
  document
  .querySelectorAll('.dropdown')
  .forEach(el=>el.classList.toggle('is-right', classOnOff))
  } 

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', Sizing4isRight )
window.addEventListener('resize', Sizing4isRight )
```

[*edit*] changed after **KXNG** remarks and dialog

for more information `classList.toggle()` second argument I made and answer with tests an explanations, [it's here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23663151/whats-the-point-of-the-second-argument-in-element-classlist-toggle/65315418#65315418)

Comment: This works great, how could I have the `.is-right` classes automatically be appended on website load also if the screen is below 769px? Not just when resizing the window.

Comment: @DevSem changed for both `documentLoaded` and `resize` events